# How do we use LIKE operator or LIKE condition in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to get the list of data / records, which are like '%JUICE%' in DynamoDB
is there any way to fetch the data like this?

Comment: did you read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html

Comment: Is the field you are searching a primary key or a regular item attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB is *not* good at wildcard searches.  That being said, you do have a few options available to you:

1. You can use the `begins_with` operator with [sort keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html).  The docs say

> begins_with (a, substr)— true if the value of attribute a begins with a particular substring

2. The `contains` operator can be used on `FilterExpression` of `scan` operations on data types STRING, SET or LIST.  More info in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html).

Keep in mind that using the `contains` keyword on `scan` operations will be an inefficient way to implement wildcard searches in DynamoDB.  You may be better off implementing this type of search outside of DynamoDB.  A common pattern is to use DynamoDB streams and Elastic Search to implement a more full-featured search capability.

Comment: Scans are quite expensive in DynamoDB but will offer that flexibility.